# Set space between rows in pdfptable

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp for creating the pdf.

Is it possible to provide space between the rows in pdfptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use table events to do that.

Java example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=95

C# example: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter05&ex=PressPreviews

Note that I made the assumption that you want cell spacing (instead of cell padding) similar to what you can see here: http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/press_previews.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can add a cell with a fixed colspan, no border and new line phrase like this:

```
PdfPCell blankRow = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\n"));
blankRow.setFixedHeight(5f);
blankRow.setColspan(4);
blankRow.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```